# Reference TypeScript lib type without using --lib

Tags: selenium, typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm writing Protractor/Selenium Webdriver code in TypeScript, including using [`executeScript`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#executeScript) to run code in the browser. I want to get the type definition for a [DOM interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3029b8fe38edde707c016a99b2edfa5b08a6e852/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L1088-L1101) that I'm passing as a parameter to `executeScript`, but I don't want to add `--lib DOM` to my `tsconfig` because most of my code runs in Node and I want to get a TS error if I accidentally use a browser-only API.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/';
var options: RequestInit = { /* ... */ };
browser.executeScript('fetch(arguments[0], arguments[1]).then(/* ... */)', url, options);
```

This errors with `Cannot find name 'RequestInit'.`

Is there any way to directly reference a type in `lib.dom.d.ts` without including the whole thing and making it available everywhere?

Comment: I tried adding `///<reference path='path/to/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts' />` to the top of this file but that still made it available in all my other files also.

Comment: Try creating a custom typings file, use `/// <ref` to include the lib, than export the types you want. This way it is a module file so it should not leak to your whole project.

Comment: @unional I'm having trouble doing this. Did you mean to create a custom `.d.ts` file with the `<ref`? How do I import that file into my source `.ts` file? I tried an `import` with no luck.

Comment: Include the folder in your tsconfig.json. Also, actually rename the custom file to `.ts` instead of `.d.ts`. Although it should work the same.